# VS error C2664 (return string from a function) C++

Tags: c++, string, return

I'm sure this was answered somewhere on the site but can not find it... I'm writing under VS10 in C++. I'm writing a class that holds details of a student. One of the members is

```
string studentName[30];
```

There should be a function that returns this string on request, this could be done using traditional C strings and a pointer however I would like to use C++ strings.

My get function looks like so:

```
string Student::getName()
{
    return studentName;
}
```

On compile, I get this error from VS10:

> Error 1   error C2664:
>   'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1
>   from 'std::string [30]' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
>   &'    f:\c++\hw1\hw1\hw3\hw3.cpp  56  1   HW3

I'm not sure what this means. If anyone can clarify I would be thankful. Also, in these get functions is it common to return a reference for the string or actual literal values (hope this is the correct lingo).

StudentName declared as such:

```
protected:
    string studentName[30];
    int  studentGrades[8];
    int  studentAge;
};
```

Comment: How studentName is defined in your class?

Comment: `string studentName[30];` is an array of thirty strings - is that really what you wanted?

Comment: `studentName` is defined to be not a string, but an array of 30 strings. You cannot pass an array of strings as a string.

Comment: you simply need to declare it as string studentName; it's enougth

Comment: @at0ma - what do you mean?

Comment: BTW this should be `string Student::getName() const;` because it does not modify the object.

Comment: @user34920 change `string studentName[30];` to `string studentName;`. Unless of course you have 30 different students all of whom have the same age, which is what your existing code describes.

Comment: string studentName[30]; means you can hold something like this ["first name" , "second name" , " etc till 30" ]> don't you want to hold just one name? like @Matt said change string studentName[30]; to string studentName

Comment: @at0ma - I see, what I wanted to do is limit the number of characters to 30.

Comment: std::string does not prealloc memory, limit when you set it, like studentName.assign("Name", 4 ), for example;

Answer (score 2):

You defined data member studentName as having type `string[30]`

```
string studentName[30];
```

At the same time function getName has return type `string`

```
string Student::getName()
```

Now please answer how has the compiler to convert an object of type `string[30]` to an object of type `string`?

I think you meant the following

```
string Student::getName()
{
    return studentName;
}
protected:
    string studentName;
    int  studentGrades[8];
    int  studentAge;
};
```

that is instead of `string studentName[30]` there should be simply `string studentName` because I do not see a greate sense to store the name of a student in 30 strings though maybe in Brasil there are names that contains 30 words.:)

Answer (score 0):

`studentName` is a `string*` (array -> pointer) but you return a `string` from the function. The error message says it all. Either return a single string or

```
string* Student::getName()
{
    return studentName;
}
```

Comment: Problem is in member declaration, not acces function

Comment: I'd venture to suggest that `string studentName;` was intended.